# How can I use weighted labels in the knn algorithm?

Tags: python, numpy, knn

I am working on my own implementation of the weighted knn algorithm.

To simplify the logic, let's represent this as a predict method, which takes three parameters:

indices - matrix of nearest j neighbors from the training sample for object i (i=1...n, n objects in total). [i, j] -  index of object from the training sample.
For example, for 4 objects and 3 neighbors:

```
indices = np.asarray([[0, 3, 1],
                      [0, 3, 1],
                      [1, 2, 0],
                      [5, 4, 3]])
```

distances - matrix of distances from j nearest neighbors from the training sample to object i. (i=1...n, n objects in total). For example, for 4 objects and 3 neighbors:

```
distances = np.asarray([[   4.12310563,    7.07106781,    7.54983444],
                       [   4.89897949,    6.70820393,    8.24621125],
                       [   0.,            1.73205081,    3.46410162],
                       [1094.09368886, 1102.55022561, 1109.62245832]])
```

labels - vector with true labels of classes for each object j of training sample. For example:

```
labels = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
```

Thus, the function signature is:

```
 def predict(indices, distances, labels):
      ....
      # return [np.bincount(x).argmax() for x in labels[indices]]
      return predict
```

In the commentary you can see the code that returns the prediction for the "non-weighted" knn-method, which does not use distances. Can you please show, how predictions can be calculated with using the distance matrix? I found the algorithm, but now I'm completely stumped becase I don't know how to realize it with numpy.

Thank you!

Comment: `[0 0 0 1 1 2]` is not a valid way to create a list. Is this an error in the question, or in your code?

Comment: @MinekPo1 oh, sorry! It was an error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
# compute inverses of distances
# suppress division by 0 warning, 
# replace np.inf with a very large number
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
    dinv = np.nan_to_num(1 / distances)
    
# an array with distinct class labels
distinct_labels = np.array(list(set(labels)))
# an array with labels of neighbors
neigh_labels = labels[indices]
# compute the weighted score for each potential label
weighted_scores = ((neigh_labels[:, :, np.newaxis] == distinct_labels) * dinv[:, :, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=1)
# choose the label with the highest score
predictions = distinct_labels[weighted_scores.argmax(axis=1)]
```